# Read a config file and get some value into elisp variable

Tags: files, read

I'm trying to read a value of variable `context` from the config file. I use something like this (but have got an error..):

```
(with-current-buffer
(insert-file-contents "/home/user/liquibase.properties")
(keep-lines "contexts" point-min point-max)
)
```

The file `/home/user/liquibase.properties` has the following structure:

```
logLevel: off
contexts: my_context
...
```

Give me a direction please. How to read the content of properties-file, filter it and store some value into a variable? To have the same result as after a call:

```
(setq ctx "my_context")
```

Comment: Point-min and point-max should be function calls. After that you need to parse the line maybe with regular expression or substring.

Comment: Thanks, John. I've changed point-min/max to (point-min/max). Now it prints the value to the current buffer. How could I parse it and save into var, instead of printing to the buffer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
(with-temp-buffer
  (insert-file-contents "config.dat")
  (keep-lines "contexts" (point-min) (point-max)) 
  (setq ctx (when (string-match "contexts: \\(.*\\)" (buffer-string))
          (match-string 1 (buffer-string)))))
```